# Need a logic to implement select button value via onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box which gives me an input from 1-20.

when i select a value, it should multiply that number with another number(say 600) and add the total to another number(say 6000).

For example, if the select input is 2,
it should display the output as 7200.

This works fine for the first input, but later if u change the select box input, it increments the value instead of adding only the selected input.

this was my logic that fails:

```
<select onchange="fun(this)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

and here's the Javascript for it.

```
function fun(t)
{
    var addedprice = t.value * 600;
    total = 6000 + addedprice;
}
```

What my problem is, i want to flush the variable value and grab the latest and generate the added price of that value only instead of incrementing the addedprice value.

Comment: Are you going to add to the last result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another variable to store the initial value.

```
var grandtotal = 6000; //Declare another variable
function fun(t){
    var addedprice = t.value * 600;
    total = grandtotal + addedprice;
}
```

Comment: well, that worked fine for just one function. How about if we have multiple function and we need to add all of their sum to a single field?

Heres a jsfiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/0j796h33/6/

Answer (score 1):

Reset the total inside the function. Something like this:

```
function fun(t){
    total = 0;
    var addedprice = t.value * 600;
    total = 6000 + addedprice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var sum = 0;
function fun(t) {
  var addedprice = t.value * 600;
  sum = 6000 + sum + addedprice;
  console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="fun(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: your code doesnt run. It has the same error as mine. it only increments and doesnt give expected results